# Why won't this print anything but null?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner

Why won't this print anything but null?

I am attempting to add new objects that are created as you answer the question and then add them to an array which I can access at a later time.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    addastudent();
}

private static void addastudent(){
    ArrayList<Object> students = new <Object> ArrayList();
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("First Name: " );
    String fname = user.next();
    System.out.println("Last Name: ");
    String lname = user.next();
    System.out.println("Major: ");
    String major = user.next();
    System.out.println("GPA: ");
    double gpa = user.nextDouble();
    student a = new student (fname,lname,major,gpa);
    students.add(a);

    System.out.println(students);




    }
```

Edit: Thank you for pointing out the toString() problem. That was it. I had forgot I told the toString() to return Null. I hate it when you miss something that simple... Thanks guys again

Comment: I'm not sure how `System.out.println` should handle an array which you pass to it (`students`), but the really strange thing here is that you seem to create a **new students array** for every **student** to be added...

Comment: The records cannot exist outside the adddastudent() method, to keep track you would need to declare the arraylist outside the method as its out of scope every time the method ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problematic items in this code.

- You should **overwrite toString** in the Student class. Otherwise it will use toString of Object, which will print something like "Student@148ccb8".
- Ensure the constructor of Student **assigns all its field** with the given parameters. You didn't provide the code, but it should look something like this:

  ```
  public class Student {

      private String firstname;
      private String lastname;
      private String major;
      private double gpa;

      public Student(
          String firstname,
          String lastname,
          String major,
          double gpa) {

          this.firstname = firstname;
          this.lastname = lastname;
          this.major = major;
          this.gpa = gpa;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {

          return "Student [firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", major="
                  + major + ", gpa=" + gpa + "]";
      }
  }
  ```

And some minors:

- Class names in Java **should start with a capital letter**. So it's Student and not student.
- Creating an ArrayList for when creating a single Student instance is not appropiate (yet), but makes sense when you extend the code to severeal Student instances.
- Using generics with Object is not using them at all!
- When using Collection classes, usually declare your variable to the common supertype.

With the last two points it's:

```
List<Student> students = new <Student>ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ArrayList<Object> students = new <Object> ArrayList();
```

To

```
ArrayList<student> students = new ArrayList<student>();
```

Add overided

> toString

method in Student class.
Hint! If you are using eclipse IDE then select your student class and go to Source menu and select generate toString method from there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please follow Java Naming Conventions and rename your method to `addStudent`, also please change `student` class to `Student`.

In this line,

```
ArrayList<Object> students = new <Object> ArrayList();
```

you're creating an `ArrayList` object, which's called `students`, `Object` is very generic, try to be more specific and change it to:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new <> ArrayList();
```

Finally, you're printing the object, and not the content. In order to print the content, you need to iterate on `students` array list and print each object, after you override `equals` in `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the full code the issue is that you have no student class. In order to use the student class you have to tell your program what it is.

Here is a simple student class to start you off.

```
public class Student {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String major;
    private double gpa;

    public Student(String fname, String lname, String major, double gpa) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.major = major;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

}
```

I haven't compiled this code but it looks like it should work.

**NOTE**: You will need to change

```
new student (fname,lname,major,gpa);
```

to

```
new Student (fname,lname,major,gpa);
```

(Notice the case change)

Answer (score 0):

`students` variable (ArrayList) should be an instance variable, not local variable.

According to above code, you will always end up with only single student in the list because you re-create the ArrayList each time when the method `addastudent` is called.